# Ambiguity of the term "vector dimensionality"

Tags: terminology

When reading about vector dimensionality, usually I find two different uses for the term.

1. It may refer to the number of data points inside a vector. Example: $v = (4, 3, -1)$ has dimensionality 3.
2. It may appear in tensor context, where vectors are unidimensional, matrices ares two-dimensional and so on.

Most of the time, the use of the term dimensionality its clear given the context. But I was just wondering if there is a less ambiguous manner to refer to this 2 cases.

Comment: Isn’t rank more common for case 2?

Comment: Who - if at all - uses the term *vector dimensionality* ?

Comment: @Hagen I'm not a english native speaker, but I do have encountered usages of this term or variants

Comment: @Randall I see, so I can solve this ambiguity if a chose rank for case 2, thanks!